# Проблема с IComparable при наследовании: используется метод базового класса

Tags: c#

Есть класс

```
class A : IComparable <A>
{
private int value;
...
...
        public int CompareTo(A obj)
        {
            if (this.value > obj.value)
                return 1;
            if (this.value < obj.value)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
}
```

Есть его потомок

```
class B : A
{
private int value2;
...
...
        public int CompareTo(B obj)
        {
            if (this.value2 > obj.value2)
                return 1;
            if (this.value2 < obj.value2)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
}
```

Если я в функции Main имею

```
List<B> list = new List<B>();
```

И вызываю метод

```
list.Sort();
```

В дебаге вижу, что сравнение происходит методом `CompareTo` из класса `А`. Почему? Список же состоит из элементов класса `B`. Как исправить?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что у Вас только класс `A` наследует интерфейс `IComparable`. Именно поэтому, несмотря на то, что класс `B` является потомком класса `A`, при сравнении используется метод `CompareTo` из базового класса.

Для решения этой проблемы необходимо чтобы класс `B` явно наследовал интерфейс `IComparable`.

```
class B : A, IComparable<B>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все работает А как правильно это называется? Просто похоже на множественное наследование, которое запрещено :). Или наследования интерфейсов это не касается?

Comment: В C# **запрещено множественное наследование только для классов**. Для интерфейсов этот запрет не действует. Однако, к множественному наследованию интерфейсов это отношения не имеет. Просто `IComparable` **обобщённый интерфейс**. А, обобщённые интерфейсы имеют ряд характерных особенностей.

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант использовать виртуальную функцию

```
class A : IComparable <A>
{
    private int value;
    ...
    protected virtual int Comparator(A obj){
        if (this.value > obj.value)
            return 1;
        if (this.value < obj.value)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    public int CompareTo(A obj)
    {
        return Comparator(obj);
    }

}

class B : A
{
    private int value2;
    ...

    protected override int Comparator(A objA){
    {
        var obj = (B)objA;
        if(obj == null) return -1;

        if (this.value2 > obj.value2)
            return 1;
        if (this.value2 < obj.value2)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```